# UDF in VSTO without creating a separate project

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-interop

Is there any way to implement an UDF in my Excel 2007 add-In **without** creating a separate project? Even if this requires using dirty tricks I'd like to know about it. Actually, I'd like to know about any exiting ways to do this.

So, if I can't... I heard something about official MS response on this problem, but i can`t find it anywhere. Could somebody provide a link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[link to similiar question on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540643/create-udf-using-vsto-and-no-vba)

The answer is no you cannot do it without a seperate project. Currently to do UDFs in Excel you need a VBA callback. No way around it, no known hacks in this area.

However I am unaware of the specific MS/MSDN response to this issue, have you trawled through the MSDN discussion forums already?