# What is the difference between a COM Add in and a VSTO Add in

Tags: com, vsto

I am trying to develop an addin for outlook, and I found a provider http://www.add-in-express.com. But, they have 2 offerings in one(http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/index.php) they allow to create COM add in Using VS 2010 and .Net Framework 4.0 (How is that possible, I always thought COM can only be create in VB6, else You have to create a COM callable Wrapper (CCW)).

The other offering is VSTO Tools (http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-vsto/index.php), Which is also using .Net Framework 4.0 and this is totally confusing.

Please help me understand.

Regards
Mohit Thakral

Answer (score 14, accepted):

VSTO uses [COM wrappers (RCW)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx) to communicate with Office via a managed API. Unfortunately - the only known way to communicate directly with Office products is by using COM components because that is the technology Office is built upon. Even when using VSTO, you still have to be aware of the COM-objects lifetime - they don't encapsulate it for you (*you still have to call [`Marshal.ReleaseCOMOjbect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx)*).

A great resource for learning about VSTO in-depth is [VSTO 2007 book by Addison-Wesley](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321533216). If you go the VSTO route - you should also pickup the [VSTO Extension Library](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7805) (*VSTO_PTExtLibs.exe*) which eases the pain of COM parameter limitations using extension methods.

I have not personally found a need to use AddIn-Express, but you may find it helps you if you don't want to invest the time in learning the VSTO framework. This choice also depends on the complexity of the solution and the time and resources you have available.

Comment: But what about "IDTExtensibility2".. thats is used for COM Add In and what about VSTO Loader

Comment: VSTO Loader is the [VSTO Runtime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/01/21/vsto-2010-runtime-components-explained-aaron-cathcart.aspx) - the API you work with when you build VSTO-based Add-ins. The VSTO Runtime still [implements IDTExtensibility2 for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/562587/175679) so you don't have to mess with the lower level COM interfaces. The goal of VSTO is to make integration with office much simpler to understand. You can certainly insert your hooks wherever you feel you need the most control.